# How to add css to input field placeholder of angular material whose appearance is set to outline and has a label?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

I want to trim the material input placeholder message with ellipses but the css gets applied to the label instead.

I am able to apply the css successfully to the material input when mat-form-field appearance is set to standard and we don't have a label. But when it's set to outline, the css gets applied to label.

I have the following html and css code:

```css
 .myFormField {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;

            .mat-form-field-infix {
                .mat-input-element {

                    &:placeholder-shown,
                    &::placeholder {
                        text-overflow: ellipsis;
                        overflow: hidden;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="myFormField">
     <mat-label> Business Name lorem</mat-label>
     <input matInput formControlName="name"
            placeholder="Business Name lorem ipsumejshdskhdsahdkasdk hasdaskdahdkjhas" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome always shows the full placeholder when the input is in focus which is why the ellipsis will not be displayed. you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896810/ellipsis-on-focused-input) for more information, firefox does support placeholder ellipsis on focus